# Iterate over hashmap of string and list in Struts2 itreator

Tags: java, struts2

I have a `HashMap<String, List<String>>`. I am iterating it by Struts2 iterator tag. But it is not iterating the list in that hashmap. My code is

```
<s:iterator value="%{userOutletMap}" var="userOutlet">
                    <tr>
                    <td><s:property value="#userOutlet.key" /><td>
                    <td>
                        <s:iterator value='<s:property value="#userOutlet.value" />' status="outletName" >
                            <s:property/></br>
                        </s:iterator>   
                    </td>
                    </tr>
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: I am using that , i just changed this line and got my result- <s:iterator value='<s:property value="#userOutlet.value" />' status="outletName" > to - <s:iterator value="#userOutlet.value" status="outletName" >

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this `%{userOutletMap}`

Just use

```
<s:iterator value="userOutletMap" var="userOutlet">
```

Comment: I am using that , i just changed this line and got my result- 
<s:iterator value='<s:property value="#userOutlet.value" />' status="outletName" >

to -
<s:iterator value="#userOutlet.value" status="outletName" >